# In ITEXT7, how to insert a visa holder without overwriting current content?

Tags: java, kotlin, itext7

I am using itext 7.0.0. I am writing a PDF and at the end, I insert a section that will contain Name/date/signature, like so:

[image]

However, in some cases, the last section is overwriting an already existing section, for example:

[image]

Here is how I insert the name/date/signature rectangle:

```
private fun placeVisa(document: Document): Document {
        val pdfCanvas = PdfCanvas(document.pdfDocument.getPage(document.pdfDocument.numberOfPages))
        val width = 200f
        val height = 100f
        val rectangle = Rectangle((document.pdfDocument.defaultPageSize.width - width) * 0.95f, // x position
                height / 2, // y position
                width, // actual width
                height) // actual height
        pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle)
        pdfCanvas.stroke()
        val canvas = Canvas(pdfCanvas, document.pdfDocument, rectangle)
        val rectangleContent = Paragraph(Text("Name, date and signature :"))
        rectangleContent.marginLeft = 5f
        canvas.add(rectangleContent)
        return document
```

How can I make it so I does not overwrite content if there is some ?

Comment: Where do you want the content to be placed in your second case? At the top of the new page? Do you create the whole document from scratch or do you modify an existing document?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I would like the content to be placed at the bottom right of the last page, if there is nothing else here yet. And the document is created from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen another approach to my problem.

Instead of drawing a rectangle, I build a table with one column and one cell.

THe height of the cell is set so that the rectanblge drawn by the table is large enough, and the witdh of the table is set so that it is large enough.

Finally, I added an horizontal alignement to the right.

```
val table = Table(1)
val cell = Cell(1,1)
cell.add("Name, date and signature :")
cell.height = 75f
table.setWidth(200f)
table.addCell(cell)
table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT)
document.add(table)
```

[image]